# How can I remove the "Menu" label on my uberMenu plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu

Good day,

How can I remove the Menu label at the top of my navigation on uberMenu? [image]

I want to remove that MENU thing above my navigation links.. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Go to your wordpress dashboard. Click UberMenu > Responsive & Mobile > Responsive Toggle Content (The text to display on the responsive toggle).

Remove the content (Menu).

Answer (score 0):

Please, uncheck the "Responsive Toggle" checkbox at "Main Ubermenu Configuration".